# How to fit a smooth polynomial?

Tags: regression, smooth-functions, regularization

Previously asked on [Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/490658/how-to-fit-a-smooth-polynomial)

We have $N$ samples of the unknown function $f(x)$ on the finite interval $[a, b]$. The samples are subject to white noise of known variance. We want to approximate the function $f(x)$ by a polynomial $P_m(x)$ of order $m$. It is, however, known, that the original function $f(x)$  is smooth in some sence. For example, let's say we know that the original $f(x)$ is [Lipschitz-continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) on the interval $[a, b]$ with some known constant $K$. Is there a standard procedure to select the best-fitting polynomial $P_m(x)$ while requiring that the polynomial satisfies the smoothness requirement.

I am not bound to Lipschitz continuity. I am happy to switch to another metric of smoothness if it is more convenient for this problem. However, the smoothness metric should be minimax. This means that the bound must apply to the smoothness of the worst point of the function, which is not necessarily the average such as L2.

Note: The question is about how to solve this problem in practice. Namely:

- Is there an analytical solution?
- Is there a known algotithm used in practice to solve this problem?
- Recommend an existing library that can perform this sort of fitting.

Comment: If I am right, no polynomial of degree at least two is Lipschitz-continuous, while all polynomials are locally Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: The polynomial only has to be smooth within $[a,b]$, not everywhere. Does this help?

Comment: The Lipschitz-continuity condition is a bit nasty here since the original function $f(x)$ could have cusps whereas a polynomial cannot. So, in this sense it seems difficult to convert this into a practical method. Wouldn't a piecewise polynomial (which can have cusps) make more sense to use?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with standard Linear Regression tools. So let the polynomial be given by $p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^m w_k x^k$. We use the fact that for smooth functions, the Lipschitz constant is equal to maximum-norm of the derivative. Hence,  we need to find an upper bound for $\|p'\|_{L^{\infty}}$ on $[a,b]$ w.r.t. the coefficients $w_k$.

Towards this end, it is useful to expand $p'$ in terms of [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the first kind, since these are [minimal w.r.t. the $\infty$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Minimal_%E2%88%9E-norm). We have:

$$\|w_k T_k(x)\|_{L^\infty([-1,+1])} \le \sum_{k}|w_k|\cdot\|T_k(X)\|_{\infty} = \sum_{k}|w_k| = \|w\|_1$$

Thus, you can try to solve your problem with a cleverly constructed [LASSO method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)), using the linear model

$$
\hat y(x, w) 
= b +\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} w_k \int T_k(x)dx 
= b + \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}w_ k\cdot \underbrace{\tfrac{1}{2} \Big({\tfrac {T_{k+1}(x)}{(k+1)}}-{\tfrac {T_{k-1}(x)}{(k-1)}}\Big)}_{=:\phi_k(x)}
= \phi(x)^T w + b
$$

1. Map the $x$-data into the interval $[-1, +1]$.
2. Construct the feature matrix $\Phi(X) = \begin{pmatrix}\phi_k(x_i)\end{pmatrix}_{ik}$
3. Solve the LASSO problem

$$(1)\qquad  \min_w \tfrac{1}{2N}\|\Phi(x)w + b - y \|_2^2 + \lambda \|w\|_1$$

Then, you are guaranteed that $\operatorname{Lip}(\hat y)=\|\hat y'\|_{L^\infty([-1,+1])} = \|\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\hat w_k T_k(x)\| \le \|\hat w\|_1$. The degree of Lipschitz continuity is controlled by $\lambda$. By solving the whole Lasso path (i.e. over a range of values of $\lambda$) you can find the best fit that satisfies your condition. This functionality is provided for example in scikit-learn: [Lasso and Elastic Net](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_lasso_coordinate_descent_path.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-lasso-coordinate-descent-path-py), [Lasso Path](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.lasso_path.html#sklearn.linear_model.lasso_path)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I will give it a try

Comment: @AleksejsFomins You're welcome. Let me know if it works ;)